# Get latest release without prerelease in GraphQL

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I'm migrating my connection with GitHub REST API to GraphQL API and I'm confused about getting latest release.

When I use this endpoint bellow to get latest release with REST API it will never return Draft releases or prereleases.

```
/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest
```

But, when I do the same with GraphQL API I can't filter that, using the query bellow I get the latest release but if it is and prerelease I'll have to query again to find another one.

```
{
  InovaFarmaApi: repository(owner: "precisaosistemas", name: "inovafarma-api") {
    ...releaseData
  }
}

fragment releaseData on Repository {
  releases (last: 2) {
      nodes {
        isPrerelease
      }
    }
}
```

Can I filter for only release and not Draft releases or prereleases?

Comment: checkout https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#repository. There is a `latestRelease` field. You could probably find out how to use it with the [explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like it.

The GitHub developer documentation has a complete listing of all GraphQL object types, their fields, and their associated parameters.  A [Repository](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/repository/) in particular documents its [releases field](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/repository/#releases); that has the Relay connection parameters and an ordering, but the only supported [ReleaseOrderField](https://developer.github.com/v4/enum/releaseorderfield/) values are `CREATED_AT` and `NAME`.

That means you need to repeat calls to page through the releases until you find one that meets your criteria.

```graphql
query GetRelease($owner: String!, $name: String!, $cursor: String) {
  repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
    releases(before: $cursor,
             last: 1,
             orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, order: DESC}) {
      pageInfo { hasPreviousPage, startCursor }
      nodes {
        isPrerelease
        ...OtherReleaseData
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you hit a release where `isPrerelease` is true (which you don't want), and `hasPreviousPage` is also true, re-run the query passing the previous `startCursor` value as the `cursor` argument.